# Multiple background images IE8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-8

Is there any jquery plugin (or any other way) to force IE8 to show multiple background images?

Comment: @mu is too short - I don't know what else to say. The reason because I want to have multiple background is realy big and extensive, and I can't see how that would help to answer my question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**CSS3 Multiple Backgrounds for Internet Explorer and legacy Mozilla Firefox**

This library brings support for multiple background images to Internet Explorer 6-8 and Firefox <=3.5 by reading the CSS code from style and link tags.

CSS3 browser support extends to background-image, background-position, background-repeat. This library only implements its own property for the shorthand style background property.

**http://plugins.jquery.com/project/multiple-bg**

[image]

**Example Usage**

*Including the Script*

All that needs to be included is the jQuery library and this script for these features to work. No extra Javascript coding is required. The minified library is only 8.7kB!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.multiple-bgs.js"></script>
```

*Writing the CSS*

Multiple backgrounds using the background property are read using this Javascript library. Notice how hover and active states are supported.

```
#ex1 {
    background: url(middle.gif) repeat-x 0 0; /* For unsupported browsers */
    background: url(left.gif) no-repeat 0 0, /* For CSS3 Browsers */
                url(right.gif) no-repeat 100% 0, 
                url(middle.gif) repeat-x 0 0;
}
#ex1:hover {
    background: url(middle-hover.gif) repeat-x 0 0; /* For unsupported browsers */
    background: url(left-hover.gif) no-repeat 0 0, /* For CSS3 Browsers */
                url(right-hover.gif) no-repeat 100% 0, 
                url(middle-hover.gif) repeat-x 0 0;
}
#ex1:active {
    background: url(middle-active.gif) repeat-x 0 0; /* For unsupported browsers */
    background: url(left-active.gif) no-repeat 0 0, /* For CSS3 Browsers */
                url(right-active.gif) no-repeat 100% 0, 
                url(middle-active.gif) repeat-x 0 0;
}
```

Comment: For those who need download link can be found here : http://www.chicowebdesign.com/blog/2010/10/21/updated-jquery-multiple-background-plug-in/

Comment: @Sonner i got the followin error in ie8 "Webpage error details

Message: Object expected
Line: 7
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: file:jquery.multiple-bgs.min.js


Message: Object expected
Line: 13
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: file:jquery.multiple-bgs.js

Comment: @eric.itzhak and Soner do you able to solve my problem as i define in above

Comment: @sonner below is my code which i use for multiple images with your above code ...........




<head>

<style type="text/css">

body
{
width:1000px;
height:1275px;




background-image:url('part1.jpg'),url('part2.jpg'),url('part3.jpg'),url('part4.jpg');
background-repeat:repeat-x,repeat-x,repeat-x,repeat;

background-position:0px 0px,0px 450px,0px 750px,0px 1245px;

background-size:100% 450px,100% 300px,100% 495px,100% 100px;
} 



</style>



<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.multiple-bgs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.multiple-bgs.js"></script>

</head>

Comment: @sonner but i got the above error(which i mention in my above comment) in ie chrome and ff shows normally correct images can you please solve this thanks

Comment: This plugin does not appear to be available any longer.

Comment: @LocalPCGuy Yes this plugin is currently in development. I hope it backs as soon as possible.

Answer (score 7):

CSS3 PIE might do what your looking for [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/)

Comment: css3pie is a fabulous little hack, but I didn't know it could do CSS multiple backgrounds???

Comment: It's not something I've ever used before, however I plan to soon. Looking at the documentation here http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/ it can be done using the -pie-background property.

Comment: This works rather nicely. Just a small gotcha, be sure to test in the actual IE8 browser - The -pie-background declaration does nothing if you try to use IE9's IE8 mode. (at least as of writing this comment)

Answer (score 5):

If it is not more than 3 images as background, you can play around the `:before` and `:after` in the css. See this [link](http://nicolasgallagher.com/multiple-backgrounds-and-borders-with-css2/) for example.

You may need to add the following in the head though if you want ie7 to behave as well:

```
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE8.js"></script>
```