# Multiple Background Images in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background-image

I want to layer background images.  CSS makes that easy, but IE doesn't support multiple background images until IE 9.  Apparently there is a way to do this with JQuery, but if I understand correctly we'd have to get the users to download a library- I may misunderstand, let me know if that's the case.

Are there other ways to layer backgrounds in IE 7 and 8?

Comment: Download a library... well technically yes, but it's just a reference to the jquery javascript file in your markup, users won't even notice...

Comment: How about layering elements with different backgrounds?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple background images IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465673/multiple-background-images-ie8)

Comment: That depends a little bit on what exactly you want to do with your layered background images. You need transparent areas where the deeper layer shine through or you just want to switch them through?

Comment: So in other words, downloading the javascript library will be transparent?  Thanks, that's what I need.

Comment: You could use PIE http://css3pie.com/

Comment: Thanks- PIE looks good.  Apparently I have at least two options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can definitely do this in older versions of IE. You will need to download the [css3Pie library](http://css3pie.com/). Once you've done that, in your css where you want to set your background properties you would use it like so:

```
#my-element 
{
    -pie-background:url(image.png) 0 0 no-repeat, url(image2.png) bottom repeat-x;
     behavior: url(path/to/PIE.htc);
}
```

Here's a link to the [documentation](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#pie-background).