# Double background images not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

here is my CSS code, please check it out.

```
body, html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-image: url(../images/header-back.jpg), url(../images/bg.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

}

It is not working in IE8 or below. Help?

-- from the answers below.
 I tried to use CSS PIE

```
body, html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
-pie-background: url(../images/header-back.jpg) repeat-x, url(../images/bg.jpg)      repeat;
behavior: url(piefolder/PIE.htc);
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

}

but still no luck,

I also tried using

```
body, html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: url(../images/header-back.jpg) repeat-x;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body:before {
content:"";
background:url(../images/bg.jpg) repeat;    
}
```

Doesn't work too, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: ie8 doesn't support that

Comment: Are there any alternative to this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465673/multiple-background-images-ie8

Comment: A simple fix in this case would be to give `html` one background and `body` the other.

Comment: genius! but just in case i would encounter this again (not in body,html) but in divs, i would like to use the CSS PIE thing.

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer 8 doesn't support CSS 3 multiple backgrounds.

Check this link :-

http://nicolasgallagher.com/multiple-backgrounds-and-borders-with-css2/